# Shoes GUI Always On Top

Tags: shoes-4

Is there a way to keep a Shoes GUI Always On Top of other windows.
In AHK I use a checkbox:

```
Gui, Add, CheckBox, x730 y520 gUpdate vCheck, Always on Top
guicontrol, , check, 1

Update:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
If Check = 1
{
    Gui, +AlwaysOnTop
}
else
{
    Gui, -AlwaysOnTop
}
```

Return